# MongoDB Exclude key C# using Criteria

Tags: c#, mongodb, projection

So, i'm been using this Object

```
public class OrdenCompra
    {
        public String Proveedor { get; set; }
        public String EmitidaPor { get; set; }
        public String NumOrden { get; set; }
        public String TipoPago { get; set; }
        public String Descuento { get; set; }
        public String Recargo { get; set; }
        public String Observacion { get; set; }
        public List<DetalleOrden> Detalle { get; set; }

        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public OrdenCompra() { this.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId(); }
        public OrdenCompra(ObjectId id) { this.Id = id; }
    }
```

I can use the regular Object and there is no problem in my app, but i need to export all the data to a html file, like a report.

Make a html markup and use jQuery to put all the data in a json file to the html.

And i just call it using the regular way

```
public String JsongetOrdenCompra(String orden)
        {
            try
            {
                return this._Collection.FindOneAs<OrdenCompra>(Query.EQ("NumOrden", orden)).ToJson();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error al obtener Orden de Compra. \n"+e.Message);
            }
        }
```

The problem is the "_id" key, so the json looks like

> {"key":"value", "bla":"bla", "_id" :
>   ObjectId("516d3f86a3e2c814ac7ca180")}

So i can't parse it ...

I know there is the SetFields(Exclude("_id")) way, but i can't use with the **FindOneAs** ...

Thanks !

Comment: Why would you want to exclude the id? The C# driver will automatically map the `_id` field in Bson to your `Id` property, so that should not be a problem? Could you describe the problem a bit more specific?

Comment: @mnemosyn _The problem is the "_id" key, so the json looks like

{"key":"value", "bla":"bla", "_id" : ObjectId("516d3f86a3e2c814ac7ca180")}

So i cant parse it ..._

Comment: Where are you trying to parse the JSON? Why don't you work with the actual C# object? What is the caller of that method?

Comment: @mnemosyn just edit the post. I need to use the data in a html page, using jQuery. Thats why i'm doing this transformation from Object to String Json

Comment: FindOneAs is just a wrapper around `FindAllAs`. The entire function is just this: `return FindAllAs<TDocument>().SetLimit(1).FirstOrDefault();`. :) You could just call `FindAllAs` and use `SetFields` as you had wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ending up using C# DataContractJsonSerializer

First, add using **System.Runtime.Serialization;** to your class (and project).

Then add [DataMember] to all your attributes like

```
[DataMember]
public String Proveedor { get; set; }
[DataMember]
public String EmitidaPor { get; set; }
//and so on
```

Now on your controller

```
ClasesProClean.OrdenCompra Orden = HO.getOrdenCompra(orden);
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer =  new DataContractJsonSerializer(Orden.GetType());
System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(ms, Orden);
String json = Encoding.Default.GetString(ms.ToArray());
```

Output:

```
{"Descuento":"5%","Detalle":[{"Cantidad":60,"CodProveedor":"45AB","Precio":600,"Producto":"BetÃºn","Total":36000},{"Cantidad":1000,"CodProveedor":"3D2","Precio":1000,"Producto":"Cera para piso flotante","Total":1000000}],"EmitidaPor":"Mario Cares","Id":{"_increment":8167808,"_machine":10740424,"_pid":5292,"_timestamp":1366114182},"NumOrden":"45","Observacion":"A la brevedad","Proveedor":"Atilio Di Gianmmarino S.","Recargo":"10%","TipoPago":"Contado"}
```

And that is what i was looking for, a readable json ;)

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB `ToJson` extension method behaves a little weird - it can be configured, but the output tends to be hard to work with. I suggest you use [`ServiceStack.Text`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text) or `JavaScriptSerializer` as a Json serializer, like so:

```
public string JsongetOrdenCompra(String orden)
{
    try
    {
        var data = this._Collection.FindOneAs<OrdenCompra>(Query.EQ("NumOrden", orden));
        var s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = s.Serialize(data);
        return result;
        // Alternatively, ServiceStack.Text.JsSerializer or 
        // extension methods like ASP.NET MVC's Json()
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error al obtener Orden de Compra. \n"+e.Message);
    }
}
```

All this isn't best practice, because you are presenting all data to the public and there is no additional level of verification and validation between the public and the database.

A better approach is usually to [create data transfer objects (DTOs)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) and map the data, for instance using [`AutoMapper`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper), like so:

```
public class OrdenDTO 
{
    public String Proveedor { get; set; }
    public String EmitidaPor { get; set; }
}

public class OrdenReadDTO : OrdenDTO
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
}

{
...
  var data = this._Collection.FindOneAs<OrdenCompra>(Query.EQ("NumOrden", orden));
  var dto = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<OrdenReadDTO>(dto);
  var s = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
  var string = s.Serialize(data);
  return string;
}
```

The idea is that the `OrdenDTO` contains all information that can be sent to the server and `OrdenReadDTO` also contains all data that can be read from the server. Typically, the ID is read only.

If you're using ASP.NET MVC or a similar framework, there are usually methods that can work with the actual domain objects, like so:

```
public ActionResult JsongetOrdenCompra(String orden)
{
    // Assuming ASP.NET MVC
    try
    {
        var data = this._Collection.FindOneAs<OrdenCompra>(Query.EQ("NumOrden", orden));
        var dto = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<OrdenReadDTO>(dto);
        return Json(dto);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error al obtener Orden de Compra. \n"+e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was a really long answer !
And i learn about the DTO way :)

Comment: It's long only because I copied the code sample twice :) The key is: a different json serializer will simply invoke the `ToString()` method and the Id will be easy to use as a string (and it will be named `Id`, not `_id`). Using the DTO is optional, but a good idea.

Comment: Finnally, i just use the DataContractJsonSerializer and it was easier and shorter for me :) 

Thanks man ;D